# Plotting Total Spending/Purchase of Unique Customers against Each Store - TSQL

Tags: t-sql, plot

I have a requirement where purchases (spending) of customers made at different stores are provided in transactions table. It is required that

1. What are the total purchases made at each store.
2. How many unique/distinct customers made purchases at each store.
3. Problematic part is that What are the total purchases of those unique customer at all stores which are spend at a particulars store. i.e. if three unique customer spent at a 'Mega Store', how to plot the total spent of those three customer against 'Mega Store'. If 4 unique customer spent at 'Alpine Store', then show total purchases of those customers against 'Alpine Store'

Challenge I am facing is that how to attain the 03rd requirement. Did some manual work in excel to display the desired results.

Below is the Table Creation Script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Cust_ID] [smallint] NULL,
    [Amount] [smallint] NULL,
    [Store] [varchar](10) NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO Transactions (Date,Cust_ID,Amount,Store)
Values
('20210222','1001',100,'Mega Store'),
('20210223','1002',200,'Z Trade'),
('20210224','1003',300,'Alpine'),
('20210227','1002',200,'Alpine'),
('20210228','1003',300,'Mega Store'),
('20210302','1001',100,'Alpine'),
('20210303','1002',200,'Mega Store'),
('20210304','1003',300,'Z Trade'),
('20210306','1001',100,'Mega Store'),
('20210307','1002',200,'Z Trade'),
('20210308','1003',300,'Alpine'),
('20210309','1004',400,'Mega Store')

select * from Transactions

-- Get Total Spend and Distinct Customer --
SELECT A.Store,SUM(A.Amount) AS Spend,B.Distinct_Customer
from Transactions A
left outer join 
(select store,count(distinct cust_id) as Distinct_Customer from Transactions group by Store) B
on A.Store = B.store
group by a.store,b.Distinct_Customer

-- Store wise Unique Cust_ids

select distinct store,cust_id from Transactions
group by store,cust_id
```

An image of working done in excel also added

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER3me.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. This *reads* like a homework assignment as well, which we certainly shouldn't be answering for you. Show us your attempts, explain why they didn't work. What research did you do to answer the question, and what about it didn't you understand? Take the [tour], as you haven't yet, and have a read of the [help], specifically reading the "how to ask" guide.

Comment: Dear, post edited, did some work but cannot figure out how to plot the total purchases of each customer against that store where he did transactions. Don't want free coding service and did not found relative post over the web.